# Asynchronous ODM of Mongodb for FastAPI / python in general

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, asynchronous, fastapi, odm

I had been using motor https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ as my driver in fastapi application to handle asynchronous db calls. But with scale, i required proper ODM support in mongodb. I had gone through multiple available odm options like beanie, motor engine and more. Some of them don't look matured (little fork and contributors). I am not saying being unpopular, the project is not useful but since i am using this in production i need some concrete and stable ODM for this. What are you guys using for such purpose and please suggest me if there is any custom way too. Thanks

Comment: If you can use MongoEngine.
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine
It's stable.

Comment: If you want to write and customize the library yourself, you will encounter many bugs, if performance is not important to you, use this.

Answer (score 1):

Beanie: https://beanie-odm.dev

First, it is async (uses the official Motor driver), which is a must if you want to use async endpoints with **FastAPI** (most operations are I/O).

Beanie allows us to define models and enforce schemas at the application level (with Pydantic and PydancticV2) and works great with the FastAPI data validation (both are using Pydantic).

It also provides simple methods for interacting with the DB (e.g., model.insert(), model.get()).

Give it a shot ! :)